# Run JavaFX Application Thread/Toolkit in Java9

Tags: javafx, migration, java-9

I'm trying to migrate a program from java 8 to java 9.

In my program I found the following code.

```
//Run JavaFX Application Thread/Toolkit
    PlatformImpl.startup(() -> {
    });
```

It tries to start the JavaFX Toolkit

Unfortunately, the PlatformImpl.startup is no longer supported in java 9.

Which substitute is there for it?

How can I start the JavaFX Toolkit?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `startup()` method is one of the methods that was promoted from the non-public class `PlatformImpl` to the public API `Platform` class in the Java 9 release. It is now fully documented in the [API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#startup-java.lang.Runnable-).

Thus the equivalent call in Java 9 is

```
Platform.startup(() -> { });
```

Note that the use cases for this method are fairly rare, and the API docs go to some lengths to emphasize this:

> In general it is not necessary to explicitly call this method, since it is invoked as a consequence of how most JavaFX applications are built.
>
> ...
>
> As noted, it is normally the case that the JavaFX Application Thread is started automatically. It is important that this method only be called when the JavaFX runtime has not yet been initialized. Situations where the JavaFX runtime is started automatically include:
>
> For standard JavaFX applications that extend `Application`, and use either the Java launcher or one of the launch methods in the `Application` class to launch the application, the FX runtime is initialized automatically by the launcher before the `Application` class is loaded.
>
> - For Swing applications that use `JFXPanel` to display FX content, the FX runtime is initialized when the first `JFXPanel` instance is constructed.
> - For SWT application that use `FXCanvas` to display FX content, the FX runtime is initialized when the first `FXCanvas` instance is constructed.
>     When an application does not follow any of these common approaches, then it becomes the responsibility of the developer to manually start the JavaFX runtime by calling this startup method.
>
> Calling this method when the JavaFX runtime is already running will result in an `IllegalStateException` being thrown - it is only valid to request that the JavaFX runtime be started once.

So, while you are in the process of making the changes you need to update your application to be Java 9 compatible, you might want to carefully consider if you need to call `startup()` at all; maybe there is a more standard and robust approach to starting your JavaFX application anyway.